# Ansi C how to dinamically call a CONSTANT

Tags: ansi-c

How can I dinamically call the right constant defined here as:

```
#define MyCONSTANT_00 "STATICVALUE"
#define MyCONSTANT_01 "STATICVALUE1"
#define MyCONSTANT_02 "STATICVALUE3"

for (Index = 0; Index < record; Index++) 
{
    myfunction(MyCONSTANT_+Index);
}
```

This return an error while compiling:

```
Undefined identifier MyCONSTANT_
```

If I call the function direclty with the constant it works fine:

```
  myfunction(MyCONSTANT_00);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't:

`#define` and corresponding replacements are handled by the pre-processor whereas the `for` loop (and the `Index` irterator) is handled by the compiler.

There is no looping mechanisms in the pre-processor.

I would suggest to define a static constant array and iterate through it in loop:

```
const char* const MyCONSTANT[] = {"STATICVALUE", "STATICVALUE1", "STATICVALUE3" }

for (Index = 0; Index < record; Index++) 
{
    myfunction(MyCONSTANT[Index]);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest making the pointer constant:  `const char *const MyCONSTANT[]`